# Windows can't copy a file that i can read manually

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1, file-transfer

As one of my HDD is showing signs of harware failure, i wanted to copy all of it's data to another one for replacement. (i am not seeing any need for an Imaging software since it is not a boot device).

During the copy of the content of this HDD, Windows (or TeraCopy) both says that some file/folders are not accessible/corrupted.

Given the context i would beleive them..... but the fact is that i can navigate into these folders and open the files using the explorer and the Notepad.

Already used :

```
chkdsk /R /F /X /V /sdcleanup
chkdsk /scan /perf X:
```

But it didn't get better.

I'm on Windows 8.1, i'd prefer not having to create a live USB (but i'll do it if it's the only option) or using an Imaging software (if the partition/disk is corrupted but some sort of caching mechanism still allows me to access it I'd prefer not to copy the partition).

Comment: If you can open the file using explorer and notepad, just save the file from there to a new file and you have yourself a copy too. Do note that the file may actually be corrupt and that notepad only loaded part of it. Given that this is explaining this behavior I posted this as a comment.

Comment: Well i also tried to open an archive file (rar) which was reported as corrupt by the explorer.... WinRar did not complain. Since i'm talking about a mass copy (~700Go), while waiting for replies i am developing a small application which will try to be doing exactly what you suggested

Comment: I'm speculating the total path length of the file exceeds 260 characters. In Windows, a path name starts from the drive letter and ends at the last character of the file name.

Comment: @geewee Would be reasonable if some of the culprits weren't at the drive's root :)

Comment: Well....
came up with https://gist.github.com/sidewinder94/d15c9aab985e12d747fc 
Still running but no errors yet.....

Comment: Well.... seems the "problematic" files are copied without any errors using the previous gist.... Seems that it validates "If you want something done right, do it yourself". So no answer here but a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... don't know what went wrong but i could successfully copy the files using a custom application who copied them bytewise.

The "can't access file or directory" / "Directory/File is corrupted" error were avoided using this small program.

https://gist.github.com/sidewinder94/d15c9aab985e12d747fc

It is not good lookig, it doesn't make any promises, is not optimized, but it can copy an entire Folder structure.